# Can two tasks in Airflow 1.X have the same name?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a DAG and a backfill DAG. They have different dag ids but same task names. I found out that once I pushed the backfill DAG to production, Airflow immediately removed the other one from Airflow UI as well as the bucket (we are using Google Composer).

I didn't find any reason for that, and I couldn't get the original DAG back, so I created a new DAG with a slightly changed DAG id and a new start date. Once I pushed it to production the backfill one is gone.

Tried to sort through the log and found this:

> INFO 2023-08-11T16:04:25.305696799Z Deactivating DAG ID blah-v4 since it was last touched by the scheduler at 2023-08-11T15:52:47.397752+00:00

This was for the original DAG, and I found the same message for the backfill. I Googled this and found it is in the source code, but the source code doesn't really tell me what it exactly means.

This led me to guess that maybe two tasks cannot have same names in Airflow, even for different DAGs. Does this make sense? I tried to Google info but couldn't find any.

Comment: I am just putting this as a comment since I don't have an answer to the bigger issue. You can definitely have tasks that are named the same across multiple DAGs. Every DAG in the instance I manage has dummy operators at the beginning and end named start and finish. Unfortunately, I don't have any insight on why the DAG is disappearing. Could you post the code snippet of declaring the DAG object?